# Automatically turn on laptop when on AC

Tags: linux, laptop, lubuntu

We are having a scheduled maintenance on the power lines and I forgot to shutdown my laptop at home. It will turn of on battery but I would like it to automatically turn on after AC is restored.

Is there any way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a BIOS/firmware issue and unrelated to UNIX/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turing on a machine isn't really OS specific, the OS itself doesn't generally control this.  It's down to the hardware.  Most common laptops (based on Intel / AMD processors) have a BIOS that lets you select what to do when AC power is restored.

To set this you will need to find how to get into your BIOS settings.  Usually you press one of F1, F2, Del as the machine powers on.  You may need to search on google for your specific laptop to find out which, or just hammer all three and hope.

Unfortunately I can't tell you were in the BIOS menus this option will be, every BIOS is different.

Comment: Thanks, I look into it.